# WPF - Clear parameter's value in application on first running

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am developing a application using WPF. After the user installed and started the application I save some parameters in application settings on User scope if the value of the parameters are null.

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.appKey == string.Empty)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.appKey = "some random key"
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

The problem is, if the user uninstall the application then install again the values of the parameters will remain.

Is it possible to known if is the first time that my application is running to clean the values and set again?

Comment: You should be cleaning these files up when you uninstall the application.  If that isn't possible - you could drop another file on the file system (Program Data) that the app looks for - keep it versioned with your assembly version - and create it if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an other bool Property "FirstTimeUse" as User scoped, Default value = True and at run time check it and if true you know it's the first use. Then set it to false and save the setting file. Next time you start your app, you know it had been started before.

```
if(Settings.Default.FirstTimeUse)
        {
            //clean the values here

            Settings.Default.FirstTimeUse = false;
            Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```